# Searching for the End marker in EXIF data

Tags: java, exif

So I'm looking here at EXIF documentation. (http://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/exif.html)
I need to do this manually, so I'm trying to store all the EXIF data into a byte array, which I can use later.
The end marker for EXIF data is FFD9 according to the link.
Would it be fine to just go about reading EXIF data up until FFD9 is encountered, and save all the EXIF data away for later use? Or is that a problem, that FFD9 could possibly occur somewhere else in the mass chunk of metadata information, while traversing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FFD8` and `FFD9` is the start and end of a JPEG image (or an EXIF thumbnail), not an EXIF chunk. EXIF data in JPEGs is stored inside a chunk marked by the `FFE1` maker, there is no end marker. You have to read the next 2 bytes to get the EXIF data length and read as much.

For example, `ffe1 1b61 4578 6966`, where `1b61` is the amount of bytes in the EXIF data chunk. 7009 bytes, once you've read these you can stop. This is the only correct way.

Some hints may be available to you to check whether you're on the correct path or not (no off by 1 errors in reading etc.). Since EXIF thumbnails are JPEGs they will end with `FFD9` as well, and a thumbnail entry will very probably be the last entry inside the EXIF chunk. So the EXIF chunk will very probably end with a `FFD9`. A new `FFEx` marker will follow, this is the start of a completely different chunk.

Again: do not search for `FFD9` and stop, though, since the EXIF chunk may contain several thumbnails which end in `FFD9`, get the header size and read accordingly.

This is for JPEG. In other image formats EXIF will be stored differently.

Comment: That makes sense. I forgot about the thumbnail data being present in the EXIF header, that could lead to FFD9 being present in the metadata itself as well. Thank you.

Comment: @nitrobuster EXIF is actually a full TIFF "file" embedded in JPEG (or other formats). TIFF does not have a length field, but you can use the length in the JFIF container format as soulseekah points out. Also note that EXIF thumbnails do not need to be JPEG encoded (or present at all), and can be interleaved with other EXIF data. So don't rely on it ending with the EOI marker.